# Conflict in using multiple JQUERY libraries

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In my web application, I have a datepicker jquery, Everything works well, until I added a new jquery codes referencing a diffrent library. This Jquery's purpose is to fixate a gridview header.

After I added this code, the datepicker stopped working. What could be causing the conflict?

[image]

Here are the codes

**1. DatePicker JQuery locatred in external JS File**

> ```
>  $(function () {
>             $("#txtdatefrom").datepicker();
>         });
>
>
>         $(function () {
>             $("#txtdateto").datepicker();
>         });
>
>
>         window.onload = function () {
>             Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
>         }
>
>         function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
>             init();
>         }
>
>         function init() {
>             $(function () {
>                 $("#txtdatefrom").datepicker();
>             });
>
>
>             $(function () {
>                 $("#txtdateto").datepicker();
>             });
>         }
>
>
>         $(function () { // DOM ready
>             init();
>         });
> ```

**3. Jquery to fix gridview header.**
After adding this the the datepicker feature stopped working.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    //not needed kasi it produced double scrolls, pero pwede din e.. ewan 
     $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#<%=grdWSR.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
        ScrollHeight: 300
      });
        }) 


        window.onload = function () {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
        }

        function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            init();
        }

        function init() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#<%=grdWSR.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
                 ScrollHeight: 300
             });
         })
     }

     $(function () { // DOM ready
         init();
     });

</script>
```

upon checking the browser console to locate the error, here is the reason:

```
jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined
```

Comment: What is the developer console panel saying?

Comment: not understood but a suggestion would be putting a common class in all **datepicker elements** and initiate all those at once like `$(".date-picker").datepicker();`

Comment: hi @ashish , basically the datepicker function and row selection to check a checkbox functions using javascript stopped working after adding new javascript command for fixing gridview header.

Comment: I have edited the question  and make it more simple to understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer. Based on research, using multiple Jquery codes or libraries can be done by using jquery.noConflict() code.

javascript for Datepicker

```
var $152 = jQuery.noConflict();
$152(function () {

    $152("#txtdatefrom").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });


//On UpdatePanel Refresh
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (prm != null) {
        prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, e) {
            if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
                $152(function () {

                    $152("#txtdatefrom").datepicker({
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true
                    });

                });

            }
        });
    };
```

for gridview header

```
 var $151 = jQuery.noConflict();

    //not needed kasi it produced double scrolls, pero pwede din e.. ewan 
    $151(document).ready(function () {
        $151('#<%=grdWSR.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
             ScrollHeight: 300
         });
     })

     window.onload = function () {
         Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
     }

     function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
         init();
         //fixGridHeader();
     }

     function init() {
         //function fixGridHeader() 

         $151(document).ready(function () {
             $151('#<%=grdWSR.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
                ScrollHeight: 300
            });
        })

    }


    $151(function () { // DOM ready
        //fixGridHeader()
        init()
    });
```

just create a variable that will be assigned with a jquery.noconflict() function. then replace all $ with the created variable per javascript. then it will work already.

reference: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to conflict in definition of `init()` function. In both the files, you have used the same name. Try renaming one of them and your issue should be fixed.

Edit: Try changing the second snippet to the following:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    //not needed kasi it produced double scrolls, pero pwede din e.. ewan 
     $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#<%=grdWSR.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
        ScrollHeight: 300
      });
        }) 


        window.onload = function () {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);
        }

        function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            fixGridHeader();
        }

        function fixGridHeader() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#<%=grdWSR.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
                 ScrollHeight: 300
             });
         })
     }

     $(function () { // DOM ready
         fixGridHeader();
     });

</script>
```

Comment: can you write an example, maybe I am doing it incorrectly. Thanks @Sujeet

Comment: @rickyProgrammer check my edit.. Also, if you still face issue, browser console will be the best starting place to find what went wrong..

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately, it still does not work successfully.

Comment: here is the error: jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined

Comment: and when I remove the second snippet / javascript code. it works just fine.